# Yii2 application is not fully uploaded into Gitlab

Tags: git, yii2, gitlab

I'm trying to push my yii2 application to my git repository, When i do that some of the configuration files is not uploaded instead of that it automatically create .gitignore file with the filename which is not pushed.

When my repository is pulled by someone else they can't access the entire project. What i have to do get all my files is uploaded to git ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is done to prevent local configuration to be published in repository.

There are two main reasons for that:

**1) Security**

The local configuration can contain sensitive data like DB credentials or access tokens for other services. It's not a good idea to share data like that in repository.

**2) Possible differences in configurations**

There might be differences in configurations based on environment. These differences are especially significant between development and production environment. For example you will probably want to use file transport for mails on your dev machine, but you won't use that on production. Another difference might be in trace level or error reporting configurations.
If you have local config files in repository it might cause the situation where you will push your development configuration and pull it into production environment.

The advanced app template contains `init` script. It's role is to set up default local configuration files from templates contained in `environments` folder. When someone clone's the repository from your gitlab they should run the init script and set up the local configuration for themselves. [See documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#preparing-application)

You can modify the templates in `environments` folder to change what exactly is generated by init script.

If you want to publish your local config files in your repository anyway you can manually add ignored files using `--force` switch (short form `-f`):

```
git add -f /path/to/the/ignored.file
```